# How can I pay Stripe with saved credit card?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using `Intent API(currency, amount only)` and `confirmCardPayment` and `Stripe rendered HTML input` to checkout.

Now I want to implement **saved credit cards**, I can save it, but I don't know how to use it to pass to `confirmCardPayment`.

My currently working `confirmCardPayment` code is this

```js
Stripe.confirmCardPayment(intent.client_secret, {
  payment_method: {
    /**
     * I'm using Vue here
     * If I'm using a saved card, what should I pass here?
     **/
    card: this.$refs.stripeCardRef.cardNumberElement,
  },
  setup_future_usage: "off_session",
});
```

If I'm using a saved card, what should I pass to confirmCardPayment, and also Intent API(I'm using currency, amount only right now)?

So I can use `stripe.paymentMethods.list` to get a customer's all saved credit cards, and return it to the front-end like this:

```js
// Server
export async function listPaymentMethods(userId: string) {
  const customer = await getOrCreateCustomer(userId);

  return stripe.paymentMethods.list({
    customer: customer.id,
    type: "card",
  });
}
```

Then, my front-end get the response like this

```
{
  "object": "list",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "pm_1GuBTiICxYQTNr22LwKB6rfy",
      "object": "payment_method",
      "billing_details": {
        "address": {
          "city": null,
          "country": null,
          "line1": null,
          "line2": null,
          "postal_code": null,
          "state": null
        },
        "email": null,
        "name": null,
        "phone": null
      },
      "card": {
        "brand": "visa",
        "checks": {
          "address_line1_check": null,
          "address_postal_code_check": null,
          "cvc_check": "pass"
        },
        "country": "US",
        "exp_month": 1,
        "exp_year": 2023,
        "fingerprint": "riI755UKjfafxa3C",
        "funding": "credit",
        "generated_from": null,
        "last4": "4242",
        "networks": {
          "available": ["visa"],
          "preferred": null
        },
        "three_d_secure_usage": {
          "supported": true
        },
        "wallet": null
      },
      "created": 1592201250,
      "customer": "cus_HPOXLjeqF24rBn",
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": [],
      "type": "card"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "url": "/v1/payment_methods"
}
```

How can I use this response data to `confirmCardPayment`?
Should my intent API need to be changed also?

Comment: If you have saved the card for future usage : https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-setup_future_usage and you're confirming payment from an existing card, you would pass the payment method id https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment#stripe_confirm_card_payment-data-payment_method. 

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This flow is covered in Stripe's documentation here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#web-create-payment-intent-off-session

The idea is that you pass the existing PaymentMethod id `pm_12345` client-side when you confirm the PaymentIntent like this:

```
stripe.confirmCardPayment(
  intent.client_secret,
  {
    payment_method: intent.last_payment_error.payment_method.id
  }
).then(function(result) {
  if (result.error) {
    // Show error to your customer
    console.log(result.error.message);
  } else {
    if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
      // The payment is complete!
    }
  }
});
```